# After deployement in IIS quartz scheduler implemented in ASP .net MVC is not working for sending Auto Mail

Tags: asp.net-mvc, quartz-scheduler

Implemented Auto Email sending scheduler using Quartz.net in Asp.Net MVC. The Code is working fine in VS IDE for sending mails based on set time period. while i am deploying in QA VM (IIS-10). The application is not sending emails

I follow few blogs and solution for setting up IIS 8/10 , But my application is not able send Auto Email after follow that.Below is the links

https://satvasolutions.com/job-scheduling-asp-mvc-quartz-scheduler/
https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/issues/180

Please provide solution or guide to setup or something need to do diffrent way.

Here my code for Auto scheduler

```
 public async static void Start()
        {
            IScheduler scheduler = await 
         StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            await scheduler.Start();
            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>().Build();
            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
                  (s =>
                     s.WithIntervalInHours(1)
                    .OnEveryDay()
                    .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0))                    
                  )                 
                .Build();
            await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
         }
```

note: "EmailJob" class will use to SMTP configuration and fetching data from Db and send mail.

After that,Will Call that method in global.asax`enter code here`

```
  protected void Application_Start()
        {

            JobScheduler.Start();
        }
```

It's been working while runing in VS 2017 on local machine , But after published to IIS-10 the scheduler is not working.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: @SeanPianka  Added My Code for reference please check above

Comment: Have you confirmed that smtp configurations are correct? May be create a test page for sending out an email without involving Quartz scheduler to confirm email are working.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood ,Yes my SMTP configuration is correct . but the use of Quartz scheduler is to Auto email send . My requirement is like the asp.net MVC application need to send report automatically by email on every hr like 1 o' clock,2 o' clock . it shoud trigger on every hour.